# Real time database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, transactions, real-time

I have developed a **Real-Time** android application which stores and retrieves 2 numbers every 3 seconds from a MYSQL database on a server, and it works fine and efficiently when the number of users is within 3 users.
But when the number of users exceeds this limit the transaction became too slow and it seems like the database can't handle this load.
My question: is there any types of databases (or another way) that can i use to deal with this issue ? 
And please keep in mind the below:
1- the problem is NOT dealing with big data, since the application is only UPDATE and doesn't INSERT a record into the database.
2- the database is existed on a server and the middle tier between the database and the application is a PHP code.

Comment: MySQL can certainly handle a small load like this.  You've coded it badly.

Comment: yes it can handle a small load caused by 3 or 5 users, but tha application is designed to serve at least 2000 users store and retrieve every 3 seconds, so you can imagine the load, and believe me its not reliable for this :(

Comment: I don't believe you.  It's still small potatoes.  You're probably doing something else wrong.  Profile the app and stop guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a security thread to avoid overlapping of requests to the database?  The response speed of your application can also influence the response time of the database. Often the problem is not the BD, the problem is the app that was developed.